# Cannot restrict vertical size of ComboBox control

Tags: visual-c++, combobox, mfc

I've created a very simple dialog-based MFC app using VS2010 in an attempt to find a solution to a problem we're having. I've dropped a combobox onto the dialog from the toolbox, and modified the `OnInitDialog` method to add a whole bunch of items to it.

I would like to restrict the vertical size of the *open* combobox. It seems that the way to do this using the designer is to click on the drop-down arrow of the combobox control, which switches the kinds of handles available to resize the control, and allows a height to be set. This height does affect the size of the closed combobox, but is supposed to control the size of the opened combobox.

This isn't the case, however. How can the vertical size of the opened drop down be restricted?

Comment: This works fine for me - clicking the drop-down allows me to select the size of the *open* combo and has no effect on the *closed* combo - are you sure you're dragging the correct handle?

Comment: You can call [`CComboBox::SetMinVisibleItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387182.aspx) at runtime to control the height of the dropdown list.

Comment: @IInspectable - That worked! Thank you. Post that as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Roger setting `No Integral height` to true allows that to work, as @IInspectable pointed out. Thanks for trying it, though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps outlined in [Setting the Size of the Combo Box and Its Drop-Down List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cta1x1t.aspx) only have the desired effect if you set the `No Integral Height` property to `True` or create the combo box with the [`CBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775796.aspx#CBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT) style. Unfortunately this usually leads to partially displayed items, as the height is specified in display units.

To get the desired height of the dropdown part of the combo box without partially clipping items you have to set it at runtime by calling [`CComboBox::SetMinVisibleItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387182.aspx) or sending a [`CB_SETMINVISIBLE` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775915.aspx). Both of these are identical where the former uses the MFC-provided member function and the latter is available whether you use MFC or not. To set the number of visible items the application must specify comctl32.dll version 6 in the manifest. To do so add the following to your application manifest:

```
<dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity
            type="win32"
            name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
            version="6.0.0.0"
            processorArchitecture="*"
            publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
            language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
    ...
</dependency>
```

If you are using Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 or later, you can add the following compiler directive to your source code instead of manually creating a manifest:

```
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

Comment: I'm glad you expanded on your answer. The `No Integral Height` property ended up being the solution we used. I'm not the developer implementing this, but he said that `SetMinVisibleItems` wasn't available on the CComboBox class actually being used. He says that it has something to do with ASCII vs. Unicode enabled controls.

Comment: @Steve Whether you use ANSI or UNICODE enabled controls doesn't seem to have an effect. You do, however, have to use common controls version 6 or later. I have updated the answer to include the required steps.

Answer (score 1):

you can use-
CComboBox::SetMinVisibleItems(int);

For seting the minimum number of visible items in the drop-down list of the current combo box control.

By specifying number of visible item in drop-down list  you can control the height of drop-down list as you required.